# MVC 5 Web api 2 Attribute Routing not working for api/v1/portfolio/1/credentials

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api

Code:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v1/portfolio")]
public class PortfolioController : ApiController
{
    [Route("")]
    [Route("index")]
    public IEnumerable<PortfolioModel> GetPortfolios()
    {
        ...
    }

    [Route("{id:int}")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(PortfolioModel))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetPortfolio(int id)
    {
        ....
    }

    [Route("{id:int}/credentials")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<CredentialsModel>))]
    private IEnumerable<CredentialsModel> GetCredentialsForId(int id)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

api/v1/portfolio works

api/v1/portfolio/index works

api/v1/portfolio/1 works

api/v1/portfolio/1/credetials  DOES NOT WORK

getting:
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found. The resource you are looking for has been removed

Can any of you gurus tell me what I'm doing wrong?

In case you ask, my WebApiConfig only has

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

and my RegisterRoutes has only:

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

as always, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change it from private to public

private IEnumerable GetCredentialsForId(int id)

to

public IEnumerable GetCredentialsForId(int id)

it will work!

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem. I'll explain for others having similar problem:

As you see in the previous code, I have the action (returning credentials) in the portfolio controler, instead I use similar action in my Credentials controler and map routed the action as if coming from the portfolio controler.

```
[Route("~/api/v1/portfolio/{id}/credentials")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<CredentialsModel>))]
    public IEnumerable<CredentialsModel> GetByPortfolioId(int id)
    {
        return _repository.FindByPortfolioId(id);
    }
```

so, I have to map to the controler in charge of returning a particular model. My problem was I had an action returning CredentialModel in a controler in charge of handling PortfolioModel.

Comment: after getting answer from BhavO, I realized this is just another way of getting the data.